# Is f continuous (i.e $f^{-1}(\,open)$ is open) $\iff$ $f(\,closed \,set \,in \,S)$ is a closed set in U?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:(S,T) \to (U,V)$, where $(S,T)$ and $(U,V)$ are topological spaces. Is f continuous (i.e $f^{-1}(\,open)$ is open) $\iff$ $f(\,closed \,set \,in \,S)$ is a closed set in U? If not is one direction true?

Comment: Your notation is pretty confusing. I'm assuming $T$ and $V$ are the topologies..?

Comment: Yes they are the topologies

Comment: Traditionally, the letter $\tau$ is used for topology which is why your notation confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \arctan(x)$. Note that $\Bbb R$ is closed in itself. $f$ is a continuous function but what is the image of $\Bbb R$ under $f$?

> Note that I had to use a closed set which is not compact since continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets. Every compact set on $\Bbb R$ is closed and bounded so in order to find a counterexample, I had to give up boundedness, hence $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Will only one direction work?